# YYYYMMDD to YYYYMM in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with DATE datatype in a table.

I am trying to retrieve the column values in YYYYMM format. My select query looks like below

```
select *
from tablename
where date column = to_char(to_date('12/31/4000','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYYMM');
```

I am getting below exception.

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Appreciate any input on this.

Comment: And we are going to be connected to the Matrix...However what version of oracle are you using? Your problem is the the date column comparison with the varchar converted date. Resulting in an implicit conversion...

Comment: If the column is a DATE type, it is not stored in a specific string format, so why are you converting to a char string?

Comment: So, the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is not YYYYMM and oracle interpreted the year as a day.. probably.

Comment: You aren't retrieving the column in any format, you're filtering a date using a string, which is going to involve an implicit conversion. What are you actually trying to do - get all the records that match a particular month?

Comment: Thanks guys. Requirement was not clear before. Request was to save the date in view as VARCHAR in YYYYMM format. I was able to achieve that using below query. 
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewname
AS
select 
column1,
to_char(columnname,'YYYYMM') as somedatecolumn
from 
tablename 
where 
date column =  to_date('12/31/4000','MM/DD/YYYY');

Once again thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest method is:

```
where to_char(datecolumn, 'YYYYMM') = '400012'
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
where to_char(datecolumn, 'YYYYMM') = to_char(to_date('12/31/4000', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYYMM');
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax-wise, the right hand date (to the right of the equals) is OK.  But you are doing a character comparison, not a date comparison.
This works for me in multiple databases:

```
select to_char (to_date('12/31/4000','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYYMM')
from dual;
```

Even though your column is named DATE_COLUMN, you are comparing based on characters in the query.

So, try this instead - this compares **based on dates** (NOT a character comparison) and truncates off the hour, minute, ETC. so you are only comparing the DAY:

```
select * from DATE_TAB 
where TRUNC(DATE1, 'DDD') = TRUNC(to_date('12/31/4000','MM/DD/YYYY'),'DDD');
```

**NOTE:** The DATE1 field above is a DATE field.  If you're DATE_COLUMN is not a DATE field, you must
convert it to a DATE datatype first (using TO_DATE, ETC.)

Comment: The `trunc` on the right-hand side is redundant, you already know there it's at midnight because you didn't specify a different time. (And the `trunc` on the left-hand side could affect performance, but that's a side-issue at the moment...)

Comment: Yes, the right hand TRUNC can be removed without affecting the result; I don't know what times he has in his table - that is the reason for the left hand TRUNC.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "date_column" is actually a date, and that you have an index on date_column, you can do something like this to return the data quickly (without truncating dates in all rows to do a comparison):

```
with dat as (
    select level as id, sysdate - (level*10) as date_column
    from dual
    connect by level <= 100
)
select id, date_column
from dat
where date_column between to_date('11/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and last_day(to_date('11/2013 23:59:59', 'MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Here I just dummy up some data with dates going back a few years.  This example picks all rows that have a date in the month of November 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If your date_column's data-type is DATE, then use

```
select *
from tablename
where TO_CHAR(date_column,'YYYYMM') = to_char (to_date('12/31/4000','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYYMM');
```

If your date_column's data-type is VARCHAR, then use:

```
select *
from tablename
where date_column = to_char (to_date('12/31/4000','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYYMM');
```

I somehow feel your **error is because** you have a **space between date and column** as 
"`date column`". If the field name in the table is "`COLUMN`", then just removing the word "`DATE`" from your original query would suffice, as:

```
select *
from tablename
where column = to_char(to_date('12/31/4000','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYYMM');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column (YYYYMMDD) is in number format, the simplest way to get YYYYMM would be

```
select floor(DATE/100)
from tablename;
```